# Oracle colsep is adding newlines. Why?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

So, I have a script:

```sql
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 10000;
set newpage NONE;
set colsep '~'
whenever sqlerror exit 1;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 255;
select TO_CHAR(je.key_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), je.message, je.id from esslog_job_errors je order by key_date desc fetch first 10 rows only;
exit;
```

Which produces:

```
2023-11-18 23:59:55~Execution error for request 6358639. Reason: ESS-07034 Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 6358639. Job error is: BIP job failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                ~ 194852628
2023-11-18 23:59:55~Execution error for request 1976388. Reason: ESS-07034 Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 1976388. Job error is: BIP job failed with delivery error.                                                                                                                                                                                            ~ 195438040
```

So, somehow the field has either a lot of space between it, or `\n~` in it. Can someone explain what's going on?

I want these fields packed in. The equivalent of:

```sql
select TO_CHAR(je.key_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ||'~'|| je.message ||'~'|| je.id from esslog_job_errors je order by key_date desc fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Which produces what I need (so, there are no spacing issues in the message field)

```
2023-11-18 23:59:55~Execution error for request 6358639. Reason: ESS-07034 Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 6358639. Job error is: BIP job failed.~194852628
2023-11-18 23:59:55~Execution error for request 1976388. Reason: ESS-07034 Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 1976388. Job error is: BIP job failed with delivery error.~195438040
```

without having to do this in every script

**EDIT**

Here is a table description:

```
DESCRIBE esslog_job_errors;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 KEY_DATE                                           DATE
 POD                                                VARCHAR2(64)
 JOB_DEFINITION                                     VARCHAR2(256)
 MESSAGE                                            VARCHAR2(4000)
 COMPONENT                                          VARCHAR2(256)
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 ERROR_TYPE                                NOT NULL NUMBER
 CREATED_DATE                              NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
 UPDATED_DATE                                       TIMESTAMP(6)
```

**EDIT**

I have since determined that it's actually inserting tabs:

```
0000230  \t  \t  \t                   ~       1   9   4   5   7   3   3
0000240   7   8  \n   2   0   2   3   -   1   1   -   1   8       2   3
0000250   :   5   9   :   5   9   ~   E   x   e   c   u   t   i   o   n
0000260       e   r   r   o   r       f   o   r       r   e   q   u   e
0000270   s   t       8   0   1   3   8   1   .       R   e   a   s   o
0000280   n   :       n   u   l   l  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t
0000290  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(je.key_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       je.message,                           --> a lot of spaces between this ...
       je.id                                 --> ... and this 
from esslog_job_errors je 
order by key_date desc fetch first 10 rows only;
```

It looks as if `message` column's datatype is `char`; is it? If so, all values are right-padded with spaces up to the maximum column length.

Example:

```
SQL> create table test (message char(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('abc');

1 row created.
```

And now:

```
SQL> select message,
  2         length(message) len,
  3         '#' || message || '#' message_2,
  4         '#' || trim(message) ||'#' message_3
  5  from test;

MESSAGE                     LEN MESSAGE_2              MESSAGE_3
-------------------- ---------- ---------------------- ----------------------
abc                          20 #abc                 # #abc#

SQL>
```

- `message` is *original* value; you don't actually see anything strange
- `len` is column's length; although I put only 3 letters in there, length is the same as column's declared length
- `message_2`: that's visible if you concatenate some character to beginning and end of that column; see the final `#` character and how *far right* it is?
- `message_3` might be your savior - `trim` *superfluous* spaces

---

Or, applied to your code:

```
select TO_CHAR(je.key_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       trim(je.message) as message,                    --> here
       je.id      
from esslog_job_errors je 
order by key_date desc fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. The data type is VARACHAR2 (I updated the question). When I apply your trim, along with all the directives, I get the same result. Your example is missing the directives, which I think is where the issue is

Comment: Aha; OK then. Try to include `SET TAB OFF`. If it doesn't help either, then - I'm afraid - you'll have to concatenate separator between every column you select, i.e. use code you already know: `select TO_CHAR(je.key_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ||'~'|| je.message ||'~'|| je.id from esslog_job_errors je order by key_date desc fetch first 10 rows only;`

Comment: I'll give some time for others to chime in. Unfortunately, that also didn't work. I ended up applying some sed post-facto to clean it up.